# ansible inventory variable precedence and levels

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

FL - Florida,
CA - California,
US - United States

hosts.ini:

```
############
### CORE ###
############

[SERVERS_FL_0102]
server01-FL
server02-FL

[SERVERS_FL_0304]
server03-FL
server04-FL

[SERVERS_CA_0102]
server01-CA
server02-CA

[SERVERS_CA_0304]
server03-CA
server04-CA


############
## GROUPS ##
############

[SERVERS_FL:children]
SERVERS_FL_0102
SERVERS_FL_0304

[SERVERS_CA:children]
SERVERS_CA_0102
SERVERS_CA_0304

[SERVERS_US_0102:children]
SERVERS_FL_0102
SERVERS_CA_0102

[SERVERS_US_0304:children]
SERVERS_FL_0304
SERVERS_CA_0304



[SERVERS_US:children]
SERVERS_FL
SERVERS_CA
```

My question to you is: does SERVERS_US_0304 group vars file have greater precedence than SERVERS_US group vars file? For me it is difficult to say, as SERVERS_US_0304 is not inside SERVERS_US. My guess is that SERVERS_US_0304 does have greater precedence than SERVERS_US as it contains fewer groups, so it is smaller. I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

> My question to you is: does `SERVERS_US_0304` group vars file have greater precedence than `SERVERS_US` group vars file?

You may have a look into [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence) and the output of

```
ansible-inventory -i inventory.ini --graph
@all:
  |--@SERVERS_US:
  |  |--@SERVERS_CA:
  |  |  |--@SERVERS_CA_0102:
  |  |  |  |--server01-CA
  |  |  |  |--server02-CA
  |  |  |--@SERVERS_CA_0304:
  |  |  |  |--server03-CA
  |  |  |  |--server04-CA
  |  |--@SERVERS_FL:
  |  |  |--@SERVERS_FL_0102:
  |  |  |  |--server01-FL
  |  |  |  |--server02-FL
  |  |  |--@SERVERS_FL_0304:
  |  |  |  |--server03-FL
  |  |  |  |--server04-FL
  |--@SERVERS_US_0102:
  |  |--@SERVERS_CA_0102:
  |  |  |--server01-CA
  |  |  |--server02-CA
  |  |--@SERVERS_FL_0102:
  |  |  |--server01-FL
  |  |  |--server02-FL
  |--@SERVERS_US_0304:
  |  |--@SERVERS_CA_0304:
  |  |  |--server03-CA
  |  |  |--server04-CA
  |  |--@SERVERS_FL_0304:
  |  |  |--server03-FL
  |  |  |--server04-FL
  |--@ungrouped:
```

> ... the last listed variables override all other variables ...
> ... Ansible gives precedence to variables that were defined more recently, more actively, and with more explicit scope. ...

If you apply tasks on the group `SERVERS_US`, the group var file of `SERVERS_US_0304` will not be read since it is not part of the (sub)tree.

```
ansible-inventory -i inventory.ini SERVERS_US --graph
@SERVERS_US:
  |--@SERVERS_CA:
  |  |--@SERVERS_CA_0102:
  |  |  |--server01-CA
  |  |  |--server02-CA
  |  |--@SERVERS_CA_0304:
  |  |  |--server03-CA
  |  |  |--server04-CA
  |--@SERVERS_FL:
  |  |--@SERVERS_FL_0102:
  |  |  |--server01-FL
  |  |  |--server02-FL
  |  |--@SERVERS_FL_0304:
  |  |  |--server03-FL
  |  |  |--server04-FL
```

And so vice versa.

```
ansible-inventory -i inventory.ini SERVERS_US_0304 --graph
@SERVERS_US_0304:
  |--@SERVERS_CA_0304:
  |  |--server03-CA
  |  |--server04-CA
  |--@SERVERS_FL_0304:
  |  |--server03-FL
  |  |--server04-FL
```

Therefore it will somehow depend on what you try to achieve. [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) gives some examples for organizing and grouping, as well the answer about [`ansible_group_priority`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58062206/6771046).